# Why does Christoffel symbol $\Gamma^0_{01}$ not vanish for weak gravitational field in my calculation?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

The metric for a static weak gravitational potential $\Phi(\vec x)$ is in first order

$g_{00}=1+2\Phi$

$g_{ij}=-(1-2\Phi$)

with all other components zero.

When I calculate Christoffel symbol

$\Gamma^\lambda_{01} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\lambda \rho}(g_{\rho0,1}+g_{\rho1,0}-g_{01,\rho})$

the last term is zero because off diagonal, the middle term is zero because no time dependence, so remaining

$\Gamma^\lambda_{01} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\lambda \rho}g_{\rho0,1}$

$g_{\rho 0}=0$ for $\rho \ne 0$, so it remains

$\Gamma^\lambda_{01} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\lambda 0}g_{00,1}$

$g^{\lambda 0}$ is zero for $\lambda \ne 0$, so for $\lambda=0$ we get

$\Gamma^0_{01} = \frac{1}{2}g^{0 0}g_{00,1} = \frac{1}{1+2\Phi} \cdot \partial_1 \Phi \approx \partial_1 \Phi$

but this is not zero. However, I always read, that all Christoffel symbols vanish in first order except $\Gamma^i_{00}, \, i=1,2,3$.

Either I'm totally blind and doing the same mistake again and again or this is simply not true...

Comment: Would you please give a reference for the claim that all Christoffel symbols vanish? Your calculation is true.

Comment: This is an approximate metric, so certain terms in Christoffel symbols will be non-zero due to non cancellation.. In Newtonian limit, $\Gamma^0_{01}$ is zero approximately due to $(1/c^2)$ term in potential $\Phi$ .

Answer (score 1):

Christoffel symbols are not zero in all reference frames. Remember they are *not* tensors!
Christoffel symbols are only zero when the local reference frame is a free-falling frame.
Your calculation is correct. What you fail to see is what it means: It means a Newtonian reference frame --let's call that way frames where Newton's law of gravitation is valid-- can never be a free-falling frame!
Now, that should be obvious.

Comment: The assumption was, that all $\Gamma$ are zero but $\Gamma^i_{00}, i=1,2,3$. But his assumption was wrong.